# Black background coming when using imagemagick for converting emf to jpeg

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a emf file, which when I am converting using imagemagick to jpeg some part of my image is coming as black. I am using following command:

```
convert "C:\Users\abhmathu\Desktop\file1\docProps\thumbnail.emf" -background white 1.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out  workaround. As mentioned in link http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/  there are some issues with jpeg format. When I tried converting it to png it works fine. And png solves my use case :-)